# What is the probability of choosing a point by a continuum of agents?

Tags: probability

I understand that the probability of choosing a point on an interval is zero. But what if there is a continuum of agents who choose a point on an interval, then what will be the expected number of agents who have chosen a particular point k?

In other words, for the one-dimensional case probability of choosing a point k on an interval $(a,b)$ with defined pdf $f(x)$ should be approximately $f(k)dx \rightarrow 0$ as $dx \rightarrow 0$.
Then, for the two-dimensional case, if we assume that there is a continuum of agents of measure $L$ (that is an interval $(0,L)$, an uncountable set) who are i.i.d and choose a point on this interval, then the probability of choosing a point should be $\int_0^L (f(k)dx)dy=\int_0^L 0dy=0$. However, if I compute the expected number of agents who choose a point k, then by the definition of probability as a frequency, I conclude that the expected number will be $f(k)L\neq 0$ and therefore it has non-zero probability.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: How do you define the "continuum of agents"? Is it a countable set, for example?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I assume an interval, that is an uncountable set.

Comment: Of curiosity: in what context did the question arise? Did it arise in analysis as analysis or in some application?

Comment: It is an application to economic theory

Comment: I think your question may make sense although it may be above my pay-grade since it seems to involve probability measures on function spaces (the selection by a continuum of agents is a random function $[0,L]\to [0,1]$). But I can at least partially address your error. By your logic for the $\int_0^L 0dy = 0$ part, the probability of an uncountable union of probability zero events is zero. This is false: in any continuous distribution the probability of a single point is zero whereas the probability of all points is one. The second $f(x)L$ part makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. For the first part I agree, for one particular point it is approximately zero (goes to zero in the limit). Never the less, as for the second part I am still confused. If I interpret $f(k)$ as a (limit) frequency of picking up the point k, then can I interpret a continuum of agents as just an infinite uncountable numbers of trials? And therefore, the expected number of successes, that is number of agents who pick up the point k, is $f(k)*L$?

Comment: @dart_kaide Perhaps it can be interpreted as an uncountable number of trials (but I still think it needs to be handled rigorously with a defined probability space). I still don't get how it follows that $f(x)$ is a frequency of picking up the point $x$ (frequency in what sense?) Like maybe each trial has $f(x)dx$ probability but $L/dx$ attempts are made in total? In this case a discrete version of your problem suggests itself.

Comment: You are right. I understood that one can not interpret $f(x)$ as a limit of a frequency. It is rather a limit of a frequency of x getting into a small interval. Therefore, the probability of choosing a point in ANY small interval is still zero. Thank you very much for you discussion!